# Remove braces from regular expression result

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

### Problem

This code:

```
select
  x::text
from
  regexp_matches( 'i1 into o2, and g1 into o17', '[gio][0-9]{1,}', 'g' ) as x;
```

Returns these results:

```
{i1}
{o2}
{g1}
{o17}
```

Rather than the following results:

```
i1
o2
g1
o17
```

### Related Links

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html

### Question

What is the most efficient way to remove the braces using PostgreSQL 9.x?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Optimal Solution

Your [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) pattern can only result in a single element per pattern evaluation, so all resulting rows are constrained to exactly *one* array element. The expression simplifies to:

```
SELECT x[1]
FROM   regexp_matches('i1 into o2, and g1 into o17', '[gio][0-9]{1,}', 'g') AS x;
```

### Other Solutions

```
SELECT unnest(x)  -- also works for cases with multiple elements per result row

SELECT trim(x::text, '{}') -- corner cases with results containing `{}`

SELECT rtrim(ltrim(x::text, '{'), '}') AS x1 -- fewer corner cases
```

**If** the pattern can or shall not match more than one time per input value, also drop the optional parameter `'g'`.

And if the function shall *always* return exactly one row, consider the subtly different variant [`regexp_match()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) introduced with Postgres 10.

In Postgres 10 or later it's also prudent to suggest the set-returning function (SRF) [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) in the `SELECT` list directly (like [Rick provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593400/remove-braces-from-regular-expression-result/10600136?noredirect=1#comment92133259_10600136)) since behavior of multiple SRFs in the `SELECT` list has finally been sanitized:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Comment: Select ... regexp_matches(....)[1] from did not work for me.  But unnest did.  (The single pattern matches several times, generating multiple rows.)  Thanks.

Comment: @aberglas: The case of the OP (without capturing parentheses in the pattern) allows only *one* element in each resulting array. The fastest solution for that is the first one. If you can have more elements in the result, you need `unnest()`. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: If your query is formatted
`select regexp_matches(column_name, regular_expression) from table_name`
then `unnest()` is the easiest way to go:
`select unnest(regexp_matches(column_name, regular_expression)) from table_name`

Comment: @RickGladwin: Yes - with reservations. See updates to this old answer.