# What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I'm trying to get a "cross join" with the result of two set-returning functions, but in some cases I don't get the "cross join", see example

**Behaviour 1**: When set lenghts are the same, it matches item by item from each set

```
postgres=# SELECT generate_series(1,3), generate_series(5,7) order by 1,2;
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               5
               2 |               6
               3 |               7
(3 rows)
```

**Behaviour 2**: When set lenghts are different, it "cross join"s the sets

```
postgres=# SELECT generate_series(1,2), generate_series(5,7) order by 1,2;
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               5
               1 |               6
               1 |               7
               2 |               5
               2 |               6
               2 |               7
(6 rows)
```

I think I'm not understanding something here, can someone explain the expeted behaviour?

Another example, even weirder:

```
postgres=# SELECT generate_series(1,2) x, generate_series(1,4) y order by x,y;
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 1
 1 | 3
 2 | 2
 2 | 4
(4 rows)
```

I am looking for an answer to the question in the title, ideally with link(s) to documentation.

Comment: My advice:  Just don't do it.  Put them in the `from` clause.

Comment: I'm doing that already, but I'm looking for optimization paths. (joining two subqueries WHEREs into one). Investigating that, I came up with this question. Are you saying that there is no expected behaviour?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Postgres 10 or newer

pads with null values for smaller set(s). Demo with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT generate_series( 1,  2) AS row2
     , generate_series(11, 13) AS row3
     , generate_series(21, 24) AS row4;
```

```
row2 | row3 | row4
-----+------+-----
   1 |   11 |   21
   2 |   12 |   22
null |   13 |   23
null | null |   24
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7ea88890d0345aa512856cfcaca4c4a4)*

[The manual for **Postgres 10**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET):

> If there is more than one set-returning function in the query's select
> list, the behavior is similar to what you get from putting the
> functions into a single `LATERAL ROWS FROM( ... )` `FROM`-clause item. For
> each row from the underlying query, there is an output row using the
> first result from each function, then an output row using the second
> result, and so on. If some of the set-returning functions produce
> fewer outputs than others, null values are substituted for the missing
> data, so that the total number of rows emitted for one underlying row
> is the same as for the set-returning function that produced the most
> outputs. Thus the set-returning functions run “in lockstep” until they
> are all exhausted, and then execution continues with the next
> underlying row.

This ends the traditionally odd behavior.

Some other details changed with this rewrite. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/release-10.html)

> - Change the implementation of set-returning functions appearing in a query's `SELECT` list (Andres Freund)
>
>   Set-returning functions are now evaluated before evaluation of scalar
>   expressions in the `SELECT` list, much as though they had been placed
>   in a `LATERAL FROM`-clause item. This allows saner semantics for cases
>   where multiple set-returning functions are present. If they return
>   different numbers of rows, the shorter results are extended to match
>   the longest result by adding nulls. Previously the results were cycled
>   until they all terminated at the same time, producing a number of rows
>   equal to the least common multiple of the functions' periods. **In
>   addition, set-returning functions are now disallowed within `CASE` and
>   `COALESCE` constructs.** For more information see [Section 37.4.8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET).

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Postgres 9.6 or older

The number of result rows (somewhat surprisingly!) is the ***lowest common multiple*** of all sets in the same `SELECT` list. (Only acts like a `CROSS JOIN` if there is no common divisor to all set-sizes!) Demo:

```
SELECT generate_series( 1,  2) AS row2
     , generate_series(11, 13) AS row3
     , generate_series(21, 24) AS row4;
```

```
row2 | row3 | row4
-----+------+-----
   1 |   11 |   21
   2 |   12 |   22
   1 |   13 |   23
   2 |   11 |   24
   1 |   12 |   21
   2 |   13 |   22
   1 |   11 |   23
   2 |   12 |   24
   1 |   13 |   21
   2 |   11 |   22
   1 |   12 |   23
   2 |   13 |   24
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=33e5fab0a2e4a8d1016519deb2f2034b)*

Documented in [manual for Postgres **9.6** the chapter **SQL Functions Returning Sets**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET), along with the recommendation to avoid it:

> Note: The key problem with using set-returning functions in the select
> list, rather than the `FROM` clause, is that putting more than one
> set-returning function in the same select list does not behave very
> sensibly. (**What you actually get if you do so is a number of output
> rows equal to the least common multiple of the numbers of rows
> produced by each set-returning function.**) The `LATERAL` syntax produces
> less surprising results when calling multiple set-returning functions,
> and should usually be used instead.

Bold emphasis mine.

A single set-returning function is OK (but still cleaner in the `FROM` list), but multiple in the same `SELECT` list is discouraged now. This was a useful feature before we had `LATERAL` joins. Now it's merely historical ballast.

Related:

- [Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)
- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)
- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any documentation for this.  However, I can describe the behavior that I observe.

The set generating functions each return a *finite* number of rows.  Postgres seems to run the set generating functions until *all* of them are on their last row -- or, more likely stop when all are back to their first rows.   Technically, this would be the least common multiple (LCM) of the series lengths.

I'm not sure why this is the case.  And, as I say in a comment, I think it is better to generally put the functions in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

There is the only note about the issue in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xfunc-sql.html). I'm not sure whether this explains the described behavior or not. Perhaps more important is that such function usage is deprecated:

> Currently, functions returning sets can also be called in the select list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the function returning set is invoked, and an output row is generated for each element of the function's result set. Note, however, that this capability is deprecated and might be removed in future releases.