# json_array_elements with null values

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5, 64 bit on windows.
I've got some irregular sized arrays. I want to use 
`json_array_elements` to expand the arrays similar to the following code

```
with outside as (select (json_array_elements('[[],[11],[21,22,23]]'::json)) aa, json_array_elements('[1,2,3]'::json)bb) 
select json_array_elements_text(aa), bb from outside
```

However, when i run this, i get

```
aa | bb
------- 
11 |  2
21 |  3
22 |  3
23 |  3
```

The empty array in column aa is dropped on the floor along with the the value of 1 in column bb

I would like to get

```
aa   | bb
---------- 
null |  1
11   |  2
21   |  3
22   |  3
23   |  3
```

Also, is this a bug in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the right functions, but the wrong `JOIN`. If you (possibly) don't have rows on one side of the `JOIN` & you want to keep the rows from the other side of the `JOIN` & use `NULL`s to "pad" rows, you'll need an [`OUTER JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
with outside as (
    select json_array_elements('[[],[11],[21,22,23]]') aa,
           json_array_elements('[1,2,3]') bb
) 
select    a, bb
from      outside
left join json_array_elements_text(aa) a on true
```

*Note*: it *may* seem strange to see `on true` as the joining condition, but it is actually quite general, when you are using [`LATERAL` joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) (which is implicit when you use a set returning function (SRF) directly in the `FROM` clause).

http://rextester.com/KNW13145

*Edit*: your original query does not involve a `JOIN` directly, but worse: you use a SRF in the `SELECT` clause. This is **almost** like a `CROSS JOIN`, but actually [it has its own rules](http://rextester.com/LLJGA9414). [Don't use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl) unless you know exactly what you are doing and why you need that.

Comment: thank you - good answer, and left join is cleaner then the case statement by klin

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. `json_array_elements_text('[null]')` returns `null`, `json_array_elements_text('[]')` does not return anything.

```
with outside as (
    select (
        json_array_elements('[[],[11],[21,22,23]]'::json)) aa, 
        json_array_elements('[1,2,3]'::json) bb
) 
select elem as aa, bb
from outside,
json_array_elements_text(case when aa::text = '[]' then '[null]'::json else aa end) elem;

 aa | bb 
----+----
    | 1
 11 | 2
 21 | 3
 22 | 3
 23 | 3
(5 rows)
```

Comment: i agree that json_array_elements_text works as you describe, why is that correct behavior?

Comment: Because there is a difference between `'[null]'::json` and `'[]'::json`. The first array contains null, the second is empty. The function cannot return anything from an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Working through my own problem, i've got one possible answer, but it seems like a mess

```
With initial as (select '[[],[11],[21,22,23]]'::json as a, '[1,2,3]'::json as b),
    Q1 as (select json_array_elements(a) as aa, json_array_elements(b) bb from initial),
    Q2 as (select ARRAY[aa->>0, aa->>1, aa->>2] as aaa, bb as bbb, ARRAY[0,1,2] as ccc from q1), 
    -- where the indicices are computed in a separate query by looping from 0 to json_array_length(...)
    Q3 as (select unnest(aaa) as aaaa, bbb as bbbb, unnest(ccc) as cccc from q2)

Select aaaa, bbbb from q3 where aaaa is not null or cccc = 0
```