# How to store comma-separated values row by row in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Input:

```
('{"user":{"status":1,"loginid":1,"userids":{"userid":"5,6"}}}')
```

I want to insert into my table like this:

```
userid    loginid    status  
---------------------------
5            1         1      
6            1         1
```

Comment: What language are you using on the app side?  Typically you would be using a JSON library which can map to a record.

Comment: Ideally if "userid" can contain multiple ids, it would be an array rather than a string value as you have. So now you need to do your own processing of that value (use one of PG's split function to split by comma), then you would insert a row for each split result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexp_split_to_table().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) Assuming that the columns are integers:

```
with input_data(data) as (
values
    ('{"user":{"status":1,"loginid":1,"userids":{"userid":"5,6"}}}'::json)
)

-- insert into my_table(userid, loginid, status)
select 
    regexp_split_to_table(data->'user'->'userids'->>'userid', ',')::int as userid,
    (data->'user'->>'loginid')::int as loginid,
    (data->'user'->>'status')::int as status
from input_data

 userid | loginid | status 
--------+---------+--------
      5 |       1 |      1
      6 |       1 |      1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be simpler with an *array* (JSON array) to begin with. The you can use [`json_array_elements_text(json)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). See:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Convert ***the list you have*** to an array with [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). Then [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(js#>>'{user,userids,userid}', ',')) AS userid
     , (js#>>'{user,loginid}')::int AS loginid
     , (js#>>'{user,status}')::int  AS status
FROM  (
   SELECT json '{"user":{"status":1,"loginid":1,"userids":{"userid":"5,6"}}}'
   ) i(js);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7fac82acb3483a2440b66f24aeaa98bd)*

I advise Postgres 10 or later for the simple form with `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

I avoid regexp functions for simple tasks. Those are powerful, but substantially more expensive.