# Inconsistent results with jsonb_array_elements_text() twice in the SELECT list

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, set-returning-functions

Why does the behavior of the query below change when the number of elements in the array changes?

The following snippet expands two arrays on the same query and has two different behaviors:

- When the two arrays have the same number of elements, one row per
  element is returned
- When the two arrays have different number of
  elements, it behaves like a `CROSS JOIN`

All of this executed in **Postgres 9.5.2**:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a text, b jsonb, c jsonb);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
('A', '["b1","b2"]', '["c1","c2"]'),
('B', '["b1","b2"]', '["c1","c2","c3"]');

SELECT a, jsonb_array_elements_text(b) b, jsonb_array_elements_text(c) c
FROM test;
```

Here is the result:

```
A  b1  c1
A  b2  c2
B  b1  c1
B  b2  c2
B  b1  c3
B  b2  c1
B  b1  c2
B  b2  c3
```

Here is what I would expect:

```
A  b1  c1
A  b1  c2
A  b2  c1
A  b2  c2
B  b1  c1
B  b2  c2
B  b1  c3
B  b2  c1
B  b1  c2
B  b2  c3
```

Comment: [The official recommendation:](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) *We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.* Postgres 9.5.17 in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list is not in the   SQL standard, where all set-returning elements go into the `FROM` list. You can do that in Postgres, but it used to exhibit surprising behavior before version 10, where it was finally sanitized.

All of this is not directly related to the datatype `jsonb` or the function `jsonb_array_elements_text()` - beyond it being a set-returning function.

If you want the Cartesian product, reliably and not depending on your version of Postgres, use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` instead (requires at least Postgres 9.3):

```
SELECT t.a, jb.b, jc.c
FROM   test t
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(t.b) jb(b)
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(t.c) jc(c)
ORDER  BY t.a, ???;  -- your desired order seems arbitrary beyond a
```

The comma in the `FROM` list (`,`) is basically short syntax for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` here.

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Explanation for your actual question:

> Why does the behavior of the query below change when the number of elements in the array changes?

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)