# Get the number of remaining days after excluding date ranges in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, gaps-and-islands

```
create table test (start date ,"end" date);

insert into test values 
      ('2019-05-05','2019-05-10')
     ,('2019-05-25','2019-06-10')
     ,('2019-07-05','2019-07-10')
     ;
```

I am looking for the following output, where for every date between the start and end the person is available only between start and end. considering for the month of may he is present for 11 days(05/05 to 05/10 and 05/25 to 05/31) and the total number of days in the month of may is 31. The output column should have 31-11 (the number of days he worked)

```
MonthDate------Days-

2019-05-01   20(31-11)
2019-06-01   20(30-10)
2019-07-01   26(31-5)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't believe your results.  Your description leaves 18 free days in May, for instance.

Comment: You'll have to decide whether to include or exclude the upper bound of ranges - consistently.

Answer (score 1):

I get slightly different results.

But the idea is to generate every date.  Then filter out the ones that are used and aggregate:

```
select date_trunc('month', dte) as yyyymm,
       count(*) filter (where t.startd is null) as available_days
from (select generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(startd)), date_trunc('month', max(endd)) + interval '1 month - 1 day', interval '1 day') dte
      from test
     ) d left join
     test t
     on d.dte between t.startd and t.endd
group by date_trunc('month', dte)
order by date_trunc('month', dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77d5418ca83d5788fa8b2982ed7cb2dc) is a db<>fiddle.

The free days in May are:

```
1
2
3
4
11

12
13
14
15
16

17
18
19
20
21

22
23
24
```

I am counting 18 of these.  So, I believe the results from this query.

If you do not want to include the end date (which is contrary to your description using "between", then the `on` logic would be:

```
 on d.dte >= t.startd and 
    d.dte < t.endd
```

But that would only get you up to 19 in May.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are inconsistent. I decided to go with *inclusive* bounds for the simplest solution:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', d)::date, count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2019-05-01', timestamp '2019-07-31', interval '1 day') d
   EXCEPT ALL
   SELECT generate_series(start_date::timestamp, end_date::timestamp, interval '1 day') x
   FROM   test
   ) sub
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', d);
```

```
date_trunc | count
-----------+------
2019-05-01 |    18
2019-06-01 |    20
2019-07-01 |    25
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=15d88b571aa333c6ab4850b9bd4f51cc)*

This generates all days of a given time frame (May to July of the year in your case) and excludes the days generated from all your date ranges.

Assuming at least Postgres 10.

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Assuming data type `date` in your table. I cast to `timestamp` for best results. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Aside: don't use the [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `start` and `end` as identifiers.

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the values. because this is test data. I have to use this query for many records

Comment: @user10449251 So define what you want instead.