# Why does this SQL unnest query result in 2 rows rather than 4?

Tags: postgresql

Relatively new SQL user question....

If my postgresql query looks like this:

```
   select
        to_timestamp((unnest(enrolled_ranges) ->> 'start_time')::float) as start_time
        , to_timestamp((unnest(enrolled_ranges) ->> 'end_time')::float) as end_time
    from student_inclusions
 where student_id = '123456'
```

And the initial enrolled_ranges json data is this:

```
{"{\"start_time\":1536652800.00007,\"end_time\":1563981839.966626}","{\"start_time\":1563982078.624668,\"end_time\":1563989693.830777}"}
```

Why does sql do this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

The first answer is what I want, I just don't understand how sql knows from the query to associate the matching start and end times. Do you have any insight?

Comment: because multiple `unnest`s in the same expression do unnest in parallel

Comment: @Bergi can you explain more please?

Comment: I have nothing to add to @SebDieBln's answer

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on set-returning functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) describes the behavior you observed:

> For each row from the underlying query, there is an output row using the first result from each set-returning function, then an output row using the second result, and so on.

See also [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39863505/10171966)