# How to apply MAX() function to array column?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group

Is there a way for me use the `MAX()` function for the `imdb_score` on each genres (ARRAYS)? As I would like to get the highest `imdb_score` per genre that would show me the title.

```
    title                                    genres         imdb_score
"Five Came Back: The Reference Films"   "{documentation}"     NULL
"Taxi Driver"                           "{crime,drama}"       8.3
"Monty Python and the Holy Grail"       "{comedy,fantasy}"    8.2
"Life of Brian"                         "{comedy}"            8
"The Exorcist"                          "{horror}"            8.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*… that would show me the title*"? Can you post the expected result of the query, please?

Comment: Seems possible by unnesting the array: `SELECT g.genre, MAX(f.imdb_score) FROM films f, LATERAL unnest(f.genres) AS g(genre) GROUP BY g.genre`

Answer (score 0):

This shows the film with the highest score **per genre**:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (genre) *
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(genres) AS genre, title, imdb_score
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY genre, imdb_score DESC NULLS LAST;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d5d8b14f3c64076084e166373de93259)*

I *think* that's what you want.

Unnest the array with [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).
About the set-returning function `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

You did not define how to break ties. (Multiple films with equally the highest score in the genre.) So this query picks an **arbitrary** winner.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Since the `imdb_score` can be `NULL`, it's crucial to add `NULLS LAST` to the descending sort order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

---

**If** you insist on `max()` ...
Also returning *all* winning films per genre:

```sql
WITH flat AS (
   SELECT unnest(genres) AS genre, imdb_score, title
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT genre, title, imdb_score
FROM  (
   SELECT genre, max(imdb_score) AS imdb_score
   FROM   flat
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub2
JOIN   flat f USING (genre, imdb_score)
ORDER  BY genre, title;
```

Much slower and convoluted. To get all winners per genre, rather use the window function [`rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT genre, title, imdb_score
FROM  (
   SELECT genre, title, imdb_score
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY genre ORDER BY imdb_score DESC NULLS LAST) AS rnk
   FROM  (
      SELECT unnest(genres) AS genre, imdb_score, title
      FROM   tbl
      ) sub
   ) sub2
WHERE  rnk = 1
ORDER  BY genre, title;
```

Does not eliminate winners with a NULL score - where no other score exists. (Unlike the solution with `max()`.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. this is the answer i needed! :) need to research on more DISTINCT ON function