# How to use LATERAL for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, lateral-join, set-returning-functions

I am using to this query to convert raster values into vector data

```
SELECT dp.*
     , g.gid gid
     , g.geom ggeom
FROM public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast
     , LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 1) as dp
JOIN raster_grid g ON dp.geom && g.geom
```

;

this resulting on

```
b1    |geom                  |
------ ----------------------+
5135.0|POINT (300005 5800015)|
4994.0|POINT (300015 5800015)|
4515.0|POINT (300025 5800015)|
3942.0|POINT (300035 5800015)|
```

As my raster data contains other bands and I want to retrieve the data from that bands too with `ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 2), ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 3)`. How can I extract all necessary values within this query? or should I do it `with as`?

Comment: You have 3 columns in value expressions but 2 in result.

Comment: Please present a consistent question. The result does not match the query. Start by disclosing Postgres and PostGIS version. And show the desired result - there are many forms to output the mentioned result ...

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb, and assuming at least Postgres 10, something like this might be what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT (dp1).*, g1.gid AS gid1, g1.geom AS geom1
     , (dp2).*, g2.gid AS gid2, g2.geom AS geom2
     , (dp3).*, g3.gid AS gid3, g3.geom AS geom3
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1) AS dp1
        , ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 2) AS dp2
        , ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 2) AS dp3
   FROM   public.t32ulc_entire_tile t
   ) rast
LEFT   JOIN raster_grid g1 ON (rast.dp1).geom && g1.geom  -- can only have 0 or 1 each!
LEFT   JOIN raster_grid g2 ON (rast.dp2).geom && g2.geom  -- can only have 0 or 1 each!
LEFT   JOIN raster_grid g3 ON (rast.dp3).geom && g3.geom  -- can only have 0 or 1 each!
;
```

The core feature is to put multiple set-returning functions in a single `SELECT` list to combine them as outlined here:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Second core feature is the syntax to [access fields of a composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING).

Comment: There are subtleties to this query. Waiting for you to clarify the question first.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a series of integers that match the number of bands of your raster in separated lateral join, then use it in `ST_PixelAsCentroids`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  i.band, 
  dp.*, 
  g.gid gid, 
  g.geom ggeom
FROM public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,3) i(band)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, i.band) AS dp
JOIN raster_grid g ON dp.geom && g.geom
```