# How to unnest two or more postgres arrays from a CTE

Tags: postgresql

From the [array-functions docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

`unnest ( anyarray, anyarray [, ... ] ) → setof anyelement, anyelement [, ... ]`

> Expands multiple arrays (possibly of different data types) into a set of rows. If the arrays are not all the same length then the shorter ones are padded with NULLs. **This form is only allowed in a query's FROM clause;**

Is it possible to use UNNEST with more than one array, when the arrays come from some table, and are not input? All the examples I've found pass the arrays as input.

Given `my_table`

```
| type | foo | bar |
+------+-----+-----+
| a    |  1  |  2  |
| a    |  3  |  4  |
| b    |  5  |  6  |
| b    |  7  |  8  |
```

How would I unnest two arrays, aggregated from the columns `foo` and `bar`?

Something like

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT type, array_agg(foo) AS foos, array_agg(bar) AS bars
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY type
)
SELECT cte.type, t.* FROM UNNEST(cte.foos, cte.bars) AS t(foos, bars)
```

But this fails with `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table cte`.

Is this possible? I know I can do it without UNNEST and simply return `type` in the CTE and then JOIN again on `my_table.type` to get all the rows with matching `type`, but in my real world query this is expensive and I'm trying to avoid repeating the scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lateral join like this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT type, array_agg(foo) AS foos, array_agg(bar) AS bars
  FROM the_table group by type
)
SELECT cte.type, t.* 
FROM cte
cross join lateral unnest(cte.foos, cte.bars) as t(foos, bars);
```

Basically this aggregates `foo` and `bar` into arrays and then flattens them back into their original structure. BTW `group by` was missing.

See [BD Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bqScMUW5T28Jib7QEWTszR/0)

Comment: Accepting this one because it is 3x more efficient (according to `explain` against my production data) than the answer by @JGH

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple unnest:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT type, array_agg(foo) AS foos, array_agg(bar) AS bars
  FROM the_table group by type
)
SELECT cte.type, unnest(cte.foos), unnest(cte.bars)
FROM cte;
```

And this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815) is relevant for understanding the behavior of multiple set returning functions in a select.