# Extract values from multiple nested arrays in a JSONB column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery, jsonb

I'm currently working on a PostgreSQL query to extract specific values from a JSONB column. Here's the query I'm using:

```
select
a.id,
(jsonb_array_elements(a.info->'attribute1')->>'value') as attribute1,
(a.info->>'attribute2') as attribute2,
(a.info->>'attribute3') as attribute3,
(jsonb_array_elements(a.info->'attribute4')->>'value') as attribute4
from a_table a
where
(cast(a.info->>'attribute3' as NUMERIC) > 0
or jsonb_array_length(a.info->'attribute1') > 0
or jsonb_array_length(a.info->'attribute4') > 0
or cast(a.info->>'attribute2' as NUMERIC) > 0)
and a.active=true
and a.data='AAA0000'
```

The problem I'm facing is that it replicates `attribute3` as many times as `attribute1` (or any other attribute that has more registers), creating incorrect results when I use this query as a subquery to sum all columns' values.

The result of this query is the following:

[image]

Here's an example of the data in the info column for the previous result. It can be seen that the previous result is not correct for attribute3.

```
{
"attribute1": [{"value": 30.45, "description": "abc1"}, {"value": 5, "description": "abc2"}, {"value": 5, "description": "abc3"}], 
"attribute2": 0, 
"attribute3": 69.36, 
"attribute4": [{"value": 18, "description": "aaa"}]
}
```

I'm looking for a way to modify the query to prevent the replication of attribute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid this multiplication of rows is to aggregate each produced set into a single array. Like:

```
SELECT a.id
     , ARRAY(SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(a.info -> 'attribute1') ->> 'value')::numeric) AS attribute1
     , (a.info ->> 'attribute2')::numeric AS attribute2
     , (a.info ->> 'attribute3')::numeric AS attribute3
     , ARRAY(SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(a.info -> 'attribute4') ->> 'value')::numeric) AS attribute4
FROM ...
```

Else you get as many rows as the the largest array has elements - in Postgres 10 or later. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

You'll need to cast to `numeric` to *"sum all columns' values"*. So this alternative sums up values within each array:

```sql
SELECT a.id
     , (SELECT sum((a1.elem ->> 'value')::numeric) FROM jsonb_array_elements(a.info -> 'attribute1') a1(elem)) AS attribute1
     , (a.info ->> 'attribute2')::numeric AS attribute2
     , (a.info ->> 'attribute3')::numeric AS attribute3
     , (SELECT sum((a4.elem ->> 'value')::numeric) FROM jsonb_array_elements(a.info -> 'attribute4') a4(elem)) AS attribute4
FROM   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fill in with NULL values, you can wrap the scalar entry into a dummy array and then unnest it just like you do your "natural" arrays.  So the 4th line becoming:

```
jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_build_array(a.info->'attribute2')) as attribute2,
```