How to compare IP address (whose column datatype is ARRAY of String) for a particular range in PostgreSQL
In PostgreSQL,
I have a column named as 'IP' whose Datatype is Array. I want to filter the records where IP are between the particular range. I tried below queries but throwing error in postgresql.
 Select * from table1 where IP BETWEEN 10.2.0.0 AND 10.15.0.8

 Select * from table1 where IP > 10.2.0.0 AND IP < 10.15.0.8

 Select * from table1 where IP::inet < '127.0.0.1'::inet

None of the above queries are working since datatype of IP column is String or String Array
None of the above queries are working since datatype of IP column is String or String Array.
Either the datatype is String or Array,  How to compare and filter the records?
I think this can work
WITH expanded_ips AS ( SELECT id, unnest(IP) AS ip_address FROM your_table), filtered_ips AS ( SELECT id FROM expanded_ips WHERE inet(ip_address) >= inet('192.168.1.1')::inet AND inet(ip_address) <= inet('192.168.1.255')::inet);

SELECT DISTINCT yt.* FROM your_table yt JOIN filtered_ips fi ON yt.id = fi.id;

When I run the below query in pgadmin it is throwing error at(::inet)
Query:
select principal_ip
from
event , unnest(principal.ip) as principal_ip
WHERE inet(principal_ip) >= inet('192.168.1.1')::inet
Error:
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got ":"

Could you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Why do you store an ip address as text? And why as an array? Don't use arrays and do you the inet data type. Content has to be between single quotes '

To obtain a list of IP addresses where each IP falls within a specific range, you can use the following :
WITH expanded_ips AS ( 
  SELECT id, IP, IP_adress
  FROM table1, UNNEST(IP) AS IP_adress
), 
filtered_ips AS ( 
  SELECT *
  FROM expanded_ips
  WHERE IP_adress::inet BETWEEN inet '10.2.0.0' AND inet '10.15.0.8'
)
SELECT *
FROM filtered_ips

Demo here

Generally recommended to put unnest in a lateral cross join rather than directly in the select because you can get weird behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815
